# How to create an alert after copied something in js

Tags: javascript

second question..

I've made a litte feature in Javascript, When you click on my logo, my email is copied.
This one works. Here you got the code.

```js
const btnCopy = document.querySelector('.btn-copy');
const txtCopy = document.querySelector('.box p');

btnCopy.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(txtCopy.innerText);
    
})
```

```html
 <div class="box">
<p style="display: none;">myemail@gmail.com</p>

<button class="btn-copy"><img src="ressources/logo.svg" class="logo"><img src="ressources/logo.svg" class="logo"></button>

 </div>
```

I would like to know how to create an alert when the email is copied..
If you can help me
Thank you, enjoy your weekend :)

Comment: What are you having trouble with? The alert itself (ie: you want to make a fancy-looking alert/toast message appear), or are you struggling with knowing when to display the alert?

Comment: You want to create a modal so that the user can see that the email has been copied to their clipboard? It is simple. Just make an empty div add some styling to it, set it's display to none initially and when user clicks the logo set the display of the div to `""` to make the alert "appear." Make sure you set the `display:""` right under `navigator.clipboard.writeText(txtCopy.innerText);` this piece of code.

Comment: I know how to create a basic window.alert, but this is not what I really want.. I would like to know how to create a pop up at the same place as the button(or really near), wich looks like the rest of my page (sorry for my english)

Comment: @Leshit then you're question isn't really related to displaying what has been copied, its more about "How do I display an alert that looks like abc" type of question, which there are plenty of. The answers you'll most likely get below will use `alert()` telling you to use `.then()` or `await` on  `writeText()`, as it isn't clear by your question if you are having trouble with knowing when to display the alert, or how to make a custom alert. btw, your english is fine, you just need to add more details to your question about what you actually mean by an "alert" if that is not what you want.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to explain clearly what i want, js is brand new for me so it's a bit tough for me to understand and tell what cause me troubles..  I dont want that classic window.alert i need to make appear a little custom popup for something like 3 sec just next to my button after that the mail is copied, i want to make it disappear then.. I alreday know this is a simple thing but..

Comment: @Leshit _"I dont want that classic window.alert i need to make appear a little custom popup for something like 3 sec just next to my button"_ - you've explained it pretty well here, you should include this information in your question. You can provide some more details about how you want the alert to look, such as its colour, how big it should be, etc.. If you can provide an example of how it should look that will also clarify your question. You can also google search some terms such as "custom modal alert", "toast messages" for some examples of different alerts and find tutorials for those

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.clipboard.writeText()` This returns a promise and it can be handled like any async task.

```js
const btnCopy = document.querySelector('.btn-copy');
const txtCopy = document.querySelector('.box p');

btnCopy.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(txtCopy.innerText).then(() => {
//show scuccess message.
alert('Email copeid successfully')
}).catch(() => {
//show error message.
alert('Something went wrong!')
});
    
})
```

```html
 <div class="box">
<p style="display: none;">myemail@gmail.com</p>

<button class="btn-copy"><img src="ressources/logo.svg" class="logo"><img src="ressources/logo.svg" class="logo"></button>

 </div>
```